# Nhibernate MySql DateTime issue c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, nhibernate, datetime

I've met an issue at attempt to request data from MySql database.

For instance:
I have a table user_data which contains lots of fields including user_id which is string and day which is date. At attempt to request data using manually created SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `alt_database`.`user_data` 
where user_id = '54sdfjghwegFDqwgf' and day = '2011-10-31';
```

It retrieves everything fine. But at attempt to request the same data using Nhibernate:

```
string customer_id = "54sdfjghwegFDqwgf";
DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse("2011-10-31");
var criteria = TheSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(user_data));
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("user_id", customer_id) & Restrictions.Eq("Day", day))
        .List<user_data>();
```

It retrieves 0 records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Dmitry

Comment: I'd highly recommend using [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) to help debug projects using NHibernate. It provides a lot of additional info to help you spot the problem.

Comment: It would help if you included the class mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out!

Unfortunately, I had to use raw sql query: using CreateSQLQuery and then adding Scalars for each field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Criteria part is not quite right. also day is not defined.  you have DT defined instead.

```
string customer_id = "54sdfjghwegFDqwgf";   
DateTime day = DateTime.Parse("2011-10-31");   
var criteria = TheSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(user_data))  
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("user_id", customer_id))  
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Day", day))   
  .List<user_data>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this snippet retrieved the same result - 0 hits. The funniest thing: if I change date to 2010-10-13 it will retrieve expected hits. =)

Comment: is it just a midnight based date?  2010-10-31 00:00:00  sounds like it might be what @Sly is suggesting

Comment: It would also be a good idea to log the SQL generated to a log file or the console so that you can see the query it outputs

Comment: You see... I can retrieve the same data using raw sql and can't using nhibernate =(. Btw, Sly's solution also doesn't work. Will be trying to retentive sql query generated by nhibernate.

Comment: is the data there for the user_id and the and the date specified?  it seems strange that it works as expected if the date is changed.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because NHibernate puts time in query. You can do something like:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Between("Day", day, day.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)));
```